# Bootstrap 4 slider text only testimonals

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, sliders

I am trying to create just a testimonial sliders in Bootstrap 4 which will be using custom post types in WordPress but I am struggling to just get the slider to work.

So my question to you is, how do I just have the text in the carousel? When I comment out the image it doesn't work and have searched the web on how to do this but there is not much adoption for BS4 which is frustrating!

```
<div class="testimonial-Slider">
  <div class="container">
      <div class="row">

<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="http://lorempixel.com/960/300/" alt="First slide">

    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3>Test Headings</h3>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the indu</p>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="http://lorempixel.com/960/300/" alt="Second slide">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Test Headings</h3>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the indu</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="http://lorempixel.com/960/300/" alt="Third slide">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Test Headings</h3>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the indu</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I am pretty confident I can get the custom post type and WP Query working fine but it is this that I am having issues with!

Cheers folks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.carousel-caption` uses `position:absolute` so it doesn't takes up space inside it's parent. The image it's filling the space, giving height.

Use `position: relative`. Check all the properties applied to `.carousel-caption`, they probably cause some other issue with what you want.

Or just create a new class inside `.carousel-item` like `.carousel-caption-custom` and only use the css you need on it.

Comment: Thanks for this, it has helped me out and now it is solved, cheers again!